# SQL query how do i group by name in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT R.CALL,
       P.NAME,
       R.PID,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF( 4, CHAR(TIMESTAMP( M.ENDTIME ) - TIMESTAMP( M.START ))) AS MINUTES
FROM ROSTER R, PLAYER_ON P, MATCH M
WHERE R.CALL = P.CALL
  AND R.PID = P.PID
  AND M.START = R.START
ORDER BY R.CALL ASC, P.NAME ASC
```

Above is my query, I successfully get the desired columns from the database.

However I still have one step to go.
The sample output for the query is like:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZem5.png)

My question is: how do I sum up the total minutes group by names, for example, Edward Ellis will appear in the output only once with total minutes 573+4933.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT CALL,
       NAME,
       PID,
       SUM(MINUTES)
FROM ( 
      SELECT R.CALL,
             P.NAME,
             R.PID,
             TIMESTAMPDIFF( 4, CHAR(TIMESTAMP( M.ENDTIME ) - TIMESTAMP( M.START ))) AS MINUTES
      FROM ROSTER R, PLAYER_ON P, MATCH M
      WHERE R.CALL = P.CALL
        AND R.PID = P.PID
        AND M.START = R.START )
GROUP BY NAME
```

But there is an error says:

> SQL0119N  An expression starting with "PID" specified in a SELECT clause, 
>   HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or 
>   it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column 
>   function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

Can someone help with that?

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to use proper `join` syntax (although that has nothing to do with your error).  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use explicit `join` syntax.

Your problem is due to extraneous columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  In addition, you don't need the subquery:

```
  SELECT P.NAME, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(M.ENDTIME)-TIMESTAMP(M.START)))) AS MINUTES
  FROM ROSTER R JOIN
       PLAYER_ON P
       ON R.CALL = P.CALL AND R.PID = P.PID JOIN
       MATCH M
       ON M.START = R.START
  GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: There is no significant problem with the syntax given. Oracle did not support ANSI join syntax until Oracle 11. Many users and many examples use the traditional Oracle syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to use join instead of from clause. But I am still confused, when I add R.CALL in front of P.NAME in the beginning, 'CALL' is not specified. Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: @KenGeis . . . Oracle has supported proper ANSI `join` syntax since at least Oracle 9i, which was released almost 15 years ago.

Comment: Sorry for the misstatement about timing of ANSI support in Oracle. I still find your statement condescending.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your query. First, try to use JOIN instead of FROM and WHERE to connect tables. Second, you need to use Having clause to sum up the total minutes.

```
SELECT r.CALL, p.NAME, r.PID, SUM (TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(m.ENDTIME)-  TIMESTAMP(m.START)))) AS MINUTES 
    FROM ROSTER r INNER JOIN PLAYER_ON p ON r.call = p.call AND r.pid=p.pid INNER JOIN INNER JOIN MATCH m ON m.START = r.START
    GROUP BY p.NAME 
    HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(m.ENDTIME)-  TIMESTAMP(m.START)))
    ORDER BY r.CALL ASC, p.NAME ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!